# Finding Unique per group with filter

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr

My data looks like this:

```
   date schedule_id food_truck_id building_id   truck_status last_confirmed_date dsle
 2018-04-26         422            58          30 accepted_event                   0   31
 2018-04-26         422            59          30 accepted_event          2018-02-27   11
 2018-04-26         422            65          30 accepted_event          2018-03-15   12
 2018-04-26         422            88          30 accepted_event          2018-02-20    7
 2018-04-26         422            89          30 accepted_event          2018-03-22   13
 2018-04-26         422           101          30 accepted_event          2018-02-06   16
 2018-04-26         422           120          30 accepted_event          2018-03-06   14
 2018-04-26         422           135          30 accepted_event          2018-03-13   21
 2018-04-26         399            42          33 accepted_event          2018-03-15    8
 2018-04-26         399            58          33 accepted_event                   0   31
 2018-04-26         399            59          33 accepted_event          2018-03-01   11
 2018-04-26         399            65          33 accepted_event          2018-02-27   12
 2018-04-26         399            88          33 accepted_event
```

Can be reproduced using:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(17647, 17647, 17647, 17647, 
17647, 17647, 17647, 17647, 17647, 17647, 17647, 17647, 17647, 
17647, 17647, 17647, 17647), class = "Date"), schedule_id = c(422L, 
422L, 422L, 422L, 422L, 422L, 422L, 422L, 399L, 399L, 399L, 399L, 
399L, 399L, 399L, 399L, 399L), food_truck_id = c(58L, 59L, 65L, 
88L, 89L, 101L, 120L, 135L, 42L, 58L, 59L, 65L, 88L, 89L, 101L, 
120L, 135L), building_id = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L), truck_status = c("accepted_event", 
"accepted_event", "accepted_event", "accepted_event", "accepted_event", 
"accepted_event", "accepted_event", "accepted_event", "accepted_event", 
"accepted_event", "accepted_event", "accepted_event", "accepted_event", 
"accepted_event", "accepted_event", "accepted_event", "accepted_event"
), last_confirmed_date = c("0", "2018-02-27", "2018-03-15", "2018-02-20", 
"2018-03-22", "2018-02-06", "2018-03-06", "2018-03-13", "2018-03-15", 
"0", "2018-03-01", "2018-02-27", "0", "2018-03-06", "2018-03-13", 
"0", "2018-02-22"), dsle = c(31, 11, 12, 7, 13, 16, 14, 21, 8, 
31, 11, 12, 7, 13, 16, 14, 21)), .Names = c("date", "schedule_id", 
"food_truck_id", "building_id", "truck_status", "last_confirmed_date", 
"dsle"), row.names = c(142L, 223L, 379L, 455L, 495L, 589L, 806L, 
877L, 63L, 155L, 215L, 287L, 452L, 483L, 667L, 809L, 894L), class = "data.frame")
```

My goal is to only select the food_truck_id based on max(dsle) but it should be unique per date. For instance, for schedule_id 422, food_truck_id with max(dsle) is 58, it is also 58 for schedule_id 399.

What I want is, let's say for 422, it is 58, but for 399, it should be next max(dsle) other than 58.

I have tried the following but it doesn't gives what I want.

```
testxx %>% 
  group_by(schedule_id) %>% 
  distinct(food_truck_id, date, dsle) %>% 
  filter(dsle == max(dsle))
```

The result I want is following

```
date         schedule_id        food_truck_id    
2018-04-26     422                   58
2018-04-26     399                   135
```

because 135 next to 58 has max(dsle)

Comment: For `schedule_id` 399, is the reason you're returning `food_truck_id` = 135 because you have already returned `food_truck_id` 58 for the other schedule, and therefore you can't return the same `food_truck_id` twice?

Comment: @SymbolixAU Exactly. That's why I mentioned unique food_truck_id per day. Also because 135 is second max(dsle) after 58

Comment: @alistaire trucks should be grouped_by schedule_id as each schedule_id must have unique truckID on same day(date)

Comment: Ok, so you want repeated maximums set to groups they belong to such that the sum of the maxes is maximized? That's not easy.

Comment: @mt1022 it would mean the one whole schedule_id is gone.

Comment: @alistaire I am not sure what you mean here.

Comment: If a truck is a max in two groups, you set it to the one where the max of the other will be the highest. That's not too complicated. But if you've got non-negligible crossover, e.g. Truck 1 is max in groups 1-5, Truck 2 is second in 2-5 and max in 6, etc., etc., this quickly becomes a complicated combinatorics question.

Comment: @alistaire if you can do what you are saying is nto complicated, may be it's what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated to account for date**

This might be one of those occasions where a loop is the best/easiest solution.

However, it does a join operation in the loop, so there will be some optimisations that can be made

The idea is to loop over each `schedule_id`, and keep track of which `food_trucks` have already been used on which date.

If we do some pre-arranging of the data before the loop it makes things easier

```
df <- df %>%
    arrange(schedule_id, -dsle)

## pre-allocate a result data.frame
ids <- unique(df$schedule_id)
df_res <- data.frame(schedule_id = ids,
                food_truck_id = NA)

usedTrucks <- data.frame(date = as.Date(NA), 
                schedule_id = ids, 
                food_truck_id = NA_integer_)
counter <- 1

for(i in ids) {

    possibleTrucks <- df[df$schedule_id %in% i, c("date", "food_truck_id")]
    ## possible Trucks will be in order, as we have pre-arranged the data

    ## use the first one that hasn't already been used
    ## on the given date
    possibleTrucks <- anti_join(possibleTrucks, usedTrucks, by = c("date", "food_truck_id"))
    thisTruck <- possibleTrucks[1, c("food_truck_id", "date")]

    df_res[counter, 'food_truck_id'] <- thisTruck$food_truck_id

    usedTrucks[counter, "food_truck_id"] <- thisTruck$food_truck_id
    usedTrucks[counter, "date"] <- thisTruck$date

    counter <- counter + 1
}

df_res
#   schedule_id food_truck_id
# 1         399            58
# 2         422           135
```

---

If speed is an issue on a larger data set this can be re-written in `Rcpp` to make it much faster.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is running into same issue as above that when the schedule_ids are more than 2, it is repeating same truck on same date. Do you think if I share the large dataset i.e. 960 obs only, you'd be able to tweak it a bit?

Comment: thank you for your answer, because it keeps track of truck id previously used, hence on a bigger dataset, i am getting lots of NA. Instead, I want to keep track of truck id by the date such that the same truck id may not be selected for two schedule_ids on same date.

Answer (score 1):

```
p<-df %>% arrange(desc(schedule_id), desc(dsle)) %>% slice(1) %>% select(date,dsle,schedule_id,food_truck_id) 

df %>% subset(!(schedule_id%in%c(p))) %>% subset(!(dsle%in%c(p))) %>% select(date,dsle,schedule_id,food_truck_id) %>% arrange(desc(dsle)) %>% slice(1) %>% 
  rbind(p,.) %>% select(-dsle)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  date       schedule_id food_truck_id
  <date>           <int>         <int>
1 2018-04-26         422            58
2 2018-04-26         399           135
```

Comment: hi vsb, thanks for your response, this is plain dplyr right? I m trying to run this on my data and I am getting only 1 obs.

Comment: Yes this is plain dplyr. My dplyr version is ‘0.7.4’

Comment: hi vsb, thanks for your response, for some reason, I am getting dupes for schedule_id with same 58 as food_truck_id for both schedule_ids

Comment: This works perfect at the chunk of data I gave above! however, may be a little tweak is needed to make it scale on my whole data.

Comment: do you think you'll able to look if I share my data? it is just 960 obs.

Comment: yeah i just checked, it wont work with there are three schedule_ids

Comment: Probably need a loop to go through all the schedule_ids